# How to trigger a function onInit in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following function getting currently triggered by a button click:

```
export class ExhibitorDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(MapInfoWindow, { static: false }) infoWindow: MapInfoWindow

  openInfo(marker: MapMarker, content) {
    this.infoWindow.open(marker)
  }

  markers = [{
    position: {
      lat: 52.550267,
      lng: 13.4367754,
    },
    label: {
      color: ''
    },
    title: 'Marker title ',
    clickable: true,
    options: {  },
  }]

  constructor(

  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {


  }

}
```

And the view where it gets triggered on click:

```
<google-map>
   <map-info-window>{{exhibitor.doc.galleryname}}</map-info-window>

   <map-marker #markerElem 
               *ngFor="let marker of markers" 
               (mapClick)="openInfo(markerElem)">
   </map-marker>
</google-map>
```

I intend to trigger the function directly on page load, without needing the click event.
Coming from AngularJS, my first idea was to find something similar to `ng-init="openInfo(markerElem)"`, but that doesn't seem to work in modern angular.

I've also tried to add the function in the ngOnInit function, but it doesn't work either.

Any pointers?

Comment: Consider using an ngAfterViewInit method.  https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to it in ngAfterViewInt that respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child views method, because when you call ngOnInit methdo the view is not renderer yet, so this.infoWindow is undefined.

Comment: i see its what i need, but can't seem to make it work... any hint on how to trigger the function in my context?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help!

Here is what made it work at the end:

```
@ViewChild('markerElem') markerElem;

ngAfterViewInit() { 

    this.openInfo(this.markerElem, "");

}
```